# DEM / Basemap Alignment

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, coordinate-system, dem, basemap

The image below shows the problem I'm facing.
I'm trying to align a DEM with the ArcMap Imagery Basemap.
Unfortunately, I can't make them to perfectly align.
I tried changing the coordinate system to WGS_1984_Web_Mercator_Auxiliary_Sphere as I understand that is what the Basemap is using but without luck.
The DEM originally uses WGS_1984.

[image: Alignment Problem]

Comment: How big is the DEM ? Are you doing a small project or a large project area ?

Comment: The DEM is around 500 km^2 but my actual area of my study is just 100 km^2.
The problem is that the contours are no aligned either and that what I'm actually trying to correct.
That means that I have to align the whole DEM but I can't find a way.

Comment: Ok if you want you can zoom in to where 100 km are you can export the imagery and then re-project the imagery to match to your DEM projection but I am not sure how will the pixel look like. They might be a bit fuzzy but that is what I would do. I do that a lot for my small project like doing digitize on campground sites. The WGS_1984_Web_Auxiliary_Sphere is what ESRI sets their projection for all of their basemap.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.
I'm not sure I understand though.
Do you mean to remove the basemap from my layers, then zoom to the study area and then reenter it?
I tried that and nothing changed.

Comment: No, I am talking about the basemap. What I am saying here is to zoom in to the DEM area and turn it off and then you have the imagery in front of you and Export it from the File menu from your ArcMap. Get it ?

Comment: Yes got it.
But why should I export it?
I guess in order to reopen the exported file and align it by hand?
In this case, as what file type should I save it?
Excuse my ignorance, I'm fairly new to ArcMap.

Comment: The display coordinates look like UTM--what's the data frame's coordinate system? And approximately where is the data location?

Comment: Is it possible the DEM is aligned correctly but just doesn't appear to be because of the land/water interface you are seeing? (I.E. a value of 0 in the DEM may not accurately represent a shoreline)

Comment: The original coordinate system of the DEM is WGS 84.
But going to Layers----Properties----Coordinate System should change both the basemaps and DEMs coordinate system, right?
The location is Northern Peloponnese, Greece.
On your second comment, that is possible (I think).
I have used the Set Null tool to erase some wrong data appearing in the sea, just after the shoreline (I excluded values of 0).

Comment: You have set the data frame's coordinate system correctly using that method, but it is always a possibility that data is not being transformed correctly. ArcMap's imagery basemap is in Web Mercator (WGS84) by default, but just to be safe you should click the "Transformations" button at the bottom of the Coordinate Systems tab. This will list all of the geographic coordinate systems in the data frame and you can make sure that there is a proper transformation being done between each. From what you have described, though, only WGS84 would be in the list. Best to be safe, though!

Comment: I created it again from scratch just to eliminate any problems created by me trying to correct the alignment.
I can confirm that I get WGS 84 only in transformations and the problem persists.